# PowerShell unusual behavior - line breaks coming back

Tags: powershell, vsphere

I'm running a PowerShell script to pull server information from vSphere and insert it into SQL Server. Some of the vSphere users are using return lines in the Notes field. This can be annoying so I tried replacing the line breaks with ', ' like this:

```
$Report.Notes = $VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Notes | Foreach-Object {$_ -Replace "`r", ", "}
```

The script finishes and creates a .csv file with a list of the servers with a few fields.

Next I want to remove the "'s around the fields in the csv before inserting into SQL Server so I run this as a separate script:

```
 ${C:\Temp\VMReport.csv} = ${C:\Temp\VMReport.csv} -replace '"'
```

After I've run this the line breaks are back in the notes field.

Obviously I'm somewhat new to PowerShell. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Per request, here's more of the code I'm running:
~

```
    $Report = "" | Select-Object VMname,Host,ClusterName,Powerstate,MemoryGB,vCPUcount,IPaddresses,TotalVmdkSizeGB,DiskFree,DiskUsed,DatastoreName,NumCpuShares,NumMemShares,SnapshotCount,GuestOS,Notes
    $Report.VMName = $VM.name
    $Report.Host = $vm.VMHost.name
    $Report.ClusterName = ($VM | Get-Cluster).Name
    $Report.Powerstate = $vm.Powerstate
    $Report.MemoryGB = $VM.MemoryMB/1KB
    $Report.vCPUcount = $VM.NumCpu
    $Report.IPaddresses = [string]::Join(',',$VM.Guest.IPAddress)
    $Report.TotalVmdkSizeGB = $TotalHardDisksSizeGB
    $Report.DiskFree = [Math]::Round((($vm.Guest.Disks | Measure-Object -Property FreeSpace -Sum).Sum / 1GB),2)
    $Report.DiskUsed = $Report.TotalVmdkSizeGB - $Report.DiskFree
    $Report.DatastoreName = [string]::Join(',',($VMview.Config.DatastoreUrl | %{$_.Name}))
    $Report.NumCpuShares = $VMResourceConfiguration.NumCPUShares
    $Report.NumMemShares = $VMResourceConfiguration.NumMemShares
    $Report.SnapshotCount = (@($VM | Get-Snapshot)).Count
    $Report.GuestOS = $VM.Guest.OSFullName
    $Report.Notes = $VM | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Notes | Foreach-Object {$_ -Replace "`r", ", "}
    $allLines += $Report

 $allLines | Export-Csv $CSVOutputFile -Delimiter '*' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `$Report.Notes = $Report.Notes -replace '"'` ? In the first example, you do the replace operation and update the $Report.Notes. Second operation should use $Report.Notes too, not the raw :  ${C:\Temp\VMReport.csv}

Comment: how are you combining $Report.Notes back into your CSV? Seems like some code missing. Can you also post more?

Comment: You are replacing only the Carriage Return character. Not a new line. If you want to replace newlines use `'\r?\n'`

Comment: If you first replace your `cr/lf` sequences with commas and then remove the double quotes your csv is broken => mismatch of headers and fields.

Comment: It is not a good idea (and it should not be necessary) to remove the quotes around the fields in a `.csv` file. If there are e.g. commas in the `notes` field, the columns will no longer match.

Comment: Also `$Report = "" | Select-Object ...` is a very ugly PowerShell statement. To create a new object, you should use: `$Report = [PSCustomObject]@{VMName = $VM.name; Host = ....}`, see e.g.: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7804.powershell-creating-custom-objects.aspx

Comment: If you want to replace newlines use  `[System.Environment]::NewLine`